# Get method in Django's detailview

Tags: python, jquery, django

This is my `industry_employeelist` detail view and it works perfectly.

```
class industry_employeelist(DetailView):
    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industry_employeelist.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        this_industry = get_object_or_404(Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
        context['employeeList'] = self.object.employee_set.all()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        this_industry = get_object_or_404(Industry.objects.filter(user=request.user))
        this_name = request.POST['name']
        this_rank = request.POST['rank']
        this_email = request.POST['email']
        this_phone = request.POST['phone']
        this_nid = request.POST['nid']
        this_address = request.POST['address']

        employee_obj = Employee.objects.create(
            industry=this_industry, name=this_name, rank=this_rank, email=this_email,
            phone=this_phone, nid=this_nid, address=this_address
        )
        employee_obj.save()

        return redirect('app:industry_employeelist')
```

Now I want to make an auto-search suggestion for my project. Looking for a tutorial: [youtubelink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oLVZp1NQVE), and [Doc](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). When I add the `get` method to the `industry_employeelist` detail-view it does not work anymore.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  this_industry = get_object_or_404(Industry.objects.filter(user=request.user))
  if 'term' in request.GET:
      srckey = request.GET.get('term')
      suggession = this_industry.employee_set.all().filter(name__contains=srckey)
      sug_list = list()
      for i in suggession:
          sug_list.append(i.name)
          return JsonResponse(sug_list, safe=False)
  context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**Please suggest how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning on the first element in your `suggestion` and only if there's a search term in your GET request. Also you're repeating yourself by using `get_object_or_404` when you can use the already defined `get_object()` which does exactly that.

Here is an optimized version of your code:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  if 'term' in request.GET:
      # Empty list to be populated and returned
      sug_list = list() 

      # Make use of the already defined method and only fetch if there's a term in the request
      this_industry = self.get_object() 

      # Get the search term
      srckey = request.GET.get('term')

      # You don't need to fetch everything using all() to filter it out, using values_list will return the column you need which is name in this case
      sug_list = list(this_industry.employee_set.filter(name__contains=srckey).values_list('name', flat=True)) 

      # Return the sug_list
      return JsonResponse(sug_list, safe=False)

  # If we request the page without the term parameter render a response
  return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

*Note: You can improve it further by discarding the 404 error when there's no object and simply return an empty list.*

Comment: I put this code inside my `industry_employeelist` view, and now it rendered a blank page with `[]` only!

Comment: So you want to return a JsonResponse only if there's `term` in the request. I will edit my answer accordingly.